# Magento 2 Plugin not working for class Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Data\CartItemFactory

Tags: magento2.4, magento-graphql

Does anyone know how to create a plugin for the class Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Data\CartItemFactory method public function create(array $data): CartItem?

I have tried creating before, after, and around plugins but didn't work. below is the reference code:

di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Data\CartItemFactory">
   <plugin name="custom_store_qty" 
      type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Cart\Data\CartItemFactory" 
      sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Cart\Data\CartItemFactory.php:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Cart\Data;

class CartItemFactory
{
    public function aroundCreate(\Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Data\CartItemFactory $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        //Custom logic
        //die("--");
    }
}
```

Note: I need to add a new parameter in the addProductsToCart graphql mutation.
ex:

```
mutation {
    addProductsToCart(
        cartId: "jdAxK6pbDHsMCQvHG0Uc98esIRbG2YZy"
        cartItems: {
            sku: "product-sku"
            quantity: 2
            test_attribute: "test attribute data as additional option."
        }

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For this i think plugin will not work. You have to override

`Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Data\CartItem`

this file in you app/code module and then on same path you have to create

`Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Cart\Data\CartItemFactory` File.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

plugin and preference will not work because
for this specific class Magento doesn't load that class or its factory through dependency injection

```
`$cartItems[] = (new CartItemFactory())->create($cartItemData);`
```

overriding the resolver.

Magento\QuoteGraphQl\Model\Resolver\AddProductsToCart